# List method creation

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I'm creating a list of my defined objects like so

```
List<clock> cclocks = new List<clocks>();
```

for each object in the list i'm calling a method moveTime, like so

```
foreach(clock c in cclocks)
{
    c.moveTime();
}
```

is the a way i can write some cleaver thing so i can call

```
cclocks.moveTime();
```

it would then go though the list doing that method

I guess I want to create a collection method?

I'm guessing there must be some thing I can do I just don't know what.

thanks for your help

Comment: I'm sure there's a way of doing this through LINQ. I'm not a LINQ expert (yet) so someone else will be able to suggest this. Although it's really just a restatement of the foreach approach. If you want a moveTime for your collection you have to create a moveTime for your collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an extension method on `List<T>` which iterates `this` and calls `moveTime()` on each of the items in the collection. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for more information.

This approach obscures a lot of information, though. If I we're you, I'd go with the for-loop.  And if you're just calling one method on each of the objects, you can shorten the for-loop, like so:

```
// no need to declare scope if you're just doing one operation on the collection
foreach(var object in collection) object.method();
```

... Or use LINQ:

```
collection.ForEach(object => object.method());
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure but perhaps you are talking about `ForEach()` method of `List<T>`

```
cclocks.ForEach(c => c.MoveTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension method to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a class that **inherits** from

```
List<clock>
```

or create an **extension method** for `List<clock>`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to derive new class from `List<Clock>` and then add all the methods you need. Something like this:

```
public class ClocksList : List<Clock>
{
   public void MoveSingleClock(Clock clock)
   {
      clock.MoveTime();
   }

   public void MoveAllClocks()
   {
      foreach(clock c in InnerList)
      {
         MoveSingleClock(c);
      }      
   }
}
```

You can use new class like this:

```
ClocksList clocks = new ClocksList();

// Fill the list
clocks.Add(new Clock());
...
// Move time on all clocks
clocks.MoveAllClocks();

// Move single clock
Clock c = new Clock();
clocks.Add(c);
clocks.MoveSingleClock(c);
```